# Tick a checkbox in a table cell by clicking anywhere in the table cell and change background color of that cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a table with each cell containing a checkbox. I want to be able to tick the checkbox by clicking anywhere within the cell and change the color of that cell which I have done.

Now the problem is that when I tick the checkbox and then untick it, that cell is not getting that cell color back, as in the when the checkbox is unticked its cell color should be back to white. Can anyone help me? Help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UcDMW/50/

```
$(function () {
    $('table tr td').on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
                $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

            } else {
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                $(this).css('background-color', '#DFF0D8');
            }
            return;
        } else {
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

                $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);

            } else {
                $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
                $(this).css('background-color', '#DFF0D8');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It is working for me. I have tried it on chrome.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Make a click especially on the checkbox, you would notice the issue..

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar it is not working fine when checkbox is checked and then unchecked otherwise when click within cell it is working perfectly

Comment: the code can be much simpler like this http://jsfiddle.net/UcDMW/55/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could restructure like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rfL6X/)

```
$('table tr td').on('click', function(e){
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
    if (!$(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    }
    $(this).css('background-color', checkbox.is(':checked')?'#DFF0D8':'white');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rfL6X/)

Comment: Thanks working for me, BUT only for 1st round, not able to check in 2nd round click for the same cell. but managed to get work done by changing this line `checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));` to `checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply accomplish your task by the following snippet,

Try,

```
$('table tr td:has(:checkbox)').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('className');
    if($(e.target).is(':checkbox')){ return; }
    var checked = $(this).find(':checkbox')[0].checked;
    $(this).find(':checkbox')[0].checked = !checked;
});
```

Cached version

```
$('table tr td:has(:checkbox)').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('className');    
    if($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) return;
    var checkBox = $(this).find(':checkbox')[0];
    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UcDMW/52/)

Answer (score 2):

You can change your js to this:

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UcDMW/62/)

**EDIT:** now working also when clicking on td cells.

```
   $(function(){

        bindCells();
    });

    function bindCells() {
        $('table tr td').on('click', function (e) {
            var check = (e.target.type=="checkbox") ? e.target : $(this).find("input:checkbox").get(0);
            $(check).attr('checked', !check.getAttribute('checked'));
            $(this).css('background-color', (check.checked) ? '#DFF0D8' : "#FFFFFF");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Oh wait, you wanted a click any where in the td cell to act in the same way as clicking the checkbox inside?

Answer (score 1):

alert($(this).is(':checked')); Use it and check the value. It returns false when you check or uncheck the box. This because you use isChecked on table elements(table,tr,td)

Change

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

in line 4 to

```
if ($(e.target).is(':checked')) {
```